# Troubleshooting: Fixing Error 400 When Installing npm Packages from Internal Repository with @ Prefix

Tags: npm, repository, devops

**Details of the Issue:**

Hello friends,

I'm currently using JFrog Artifactory as our internal npm repository, acting as an intermediary repository. I've encountered an issue that maybe you can help with. When I intend to install an npm package that starts with "@" (such as @microsoft/signalr), something interesting happens. Instead of directly requesting @microsoft/signalr, the request converts "/" to "%2f," resulting in a request for @microsoft%2fsignalr, causing installation issues.

Testing this, I manually altered the URL using wget, and it successfully retrieved the package. However, when the request itself is made through npm, it returns a 400 bad request.

The reason behind this is that npm considers packages starting with "@" for personal accounts or private repositories. Hence, it makes this modification in its requests.

**Testing and Observations:**
I've tested certain alterations in specific areas mentioned below:

```
ubuntu@jfrog:~$ npm install @microsoft/signalr 
npm ERR! code E400
npm ERR! 400 Bad Request - GET jfrog.myrepo/artifactory/api/npm/test-npm/@microsoft%2fsignalr

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ubuntu/.npm/_logs/2024-01-24T06_23_34_172Z-debug-0.log
```

At the bottom of the log output related to this package:

**To test the repository for the rest of the packages**

```
ubuntu@jfrog:~$ npm install debug --save

added 2 packages, and audited 4 packages in 4s

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

log npm install debug --save

```
0 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'install', 'debug', '--save' ]
22 verbose logfile /home/ubuntu/.npm/_logs/2024-01-24T06_38_08_353Z-debug-0.log
31 silly fetch manifest debug@*
33 http fetch GET 200 jfrog.myrepo/artifactory/api/npm/test-npm/debug 1733ms (cache miss)
34 silly placeDep ROOT debug@4.3.4 OK for:  want: *
38 silly placeDep ROOT ms@2.1.2 OK for: debug@4.3.4 want: 2.1.2
39 timing idealTree:node_modules/debug Completed in 4ms
50 silly audit bulk request { prettier: [ '2.8.8' ], debug: [ '4.3.4' ], ms: [ '2.1.2' ] }
51 silly tarball no local data for debug@jfrog.myrepo:443/artifactory/api/npm/test-npm/debug/-/debug-4.3.4.tgz. Extracting by manifest.
60 http fetch GET 200 jfrog.myrepo/artifactory/api/npm/test-npm/debug/-/debug-4.3.4.tgz 1325ms (cache miss)
61 timing reifyNode:node_modules/debug Completed in 1334ms
72 silly ADD node_modules/debug
```

```
0 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'install', '@microsoft/signalr' ]
31 silly fetch manifest @microsoft/signalr@*
33 http fetch GET 400 jfrog.myrepo/artifactory/api/npm/test-npm/@microsoft%2fsignalr 61ms (cache skip)
34 silly placeDep ROOT @microsoft/signalr@ OK for:  want: *
36 timing idealTree:node_modules/@microsoft/signalr Completed in 0ms
41 verbose stack HttpErrorGeneral: 400 Bad Request - GET jfrog.myrepo/artifactory/api/npm/test-npm/@microsoft%2fsignalr
43 verbose pkgid @microsoft/signalr@*
46 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "@microsoft/signalr"
50 error 400 Bad Request - GET jfrog.myrepo/artifactory/api/npm/test-npm/@microsoft%2fsignalr
```

In order to test whether it downloads these types of packages or not, I tested with wget:

```
ubuntu@jfrog:~$ wget jfrog.myrepo/artifactory/api/npm/test-npm/@microsoft%2fsignalr
--2024-01-24 06:30:55--  jfrog.myrepo/artifactory/api/npm/test-npm/@microsoft%2fsignalr
Resolving jfrog.myrepo (jfrog.myrepo)... 172.32.241.226
Connecting to jfrog.myrepo (jfrog.myrepo)|172.32.241.226|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 400 
2024-01-24 06:30:55 ERROR 400: (no description).

ubuntu@jfrog:~$ wget jfrog.myrepo/artifactory/api/npm/test-npm/@microsoft/signalr
--2024-01-24 06:31:07--  jfrog.myrepo/artifactory/api/npm/test-npm/@microsoft/signalr
Resolving jfrog.myrepo (jfrog.myrepo)... 172.32.241.226
Connecting to jfrog.myrepo (jfrog.myrepo)|172.32.241.226|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 
Length: unspecified [application/json]
Saving to: ‘signalr’

signalr                                                         [ <=>                                                                                                                                      ] 637.42K  --.-KB/s    in 0.007s  

2024-01-24 06:31:10 (91.7 MB/s) - ‘signalr’ saved [652719]
```

Has anyone else encountered this issue? Is there a way to resolve this problem? Any guidance or experiences you have in this area would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your help.

---

Feel free to let me know if you have any specific changes or if you'd like adjustments made.

I have explained the work above, but only for this situation, annonymos access is open, and I also tested it with authentication, deleted the .npmrc file, and tested different modes.